# Using dplyr for exploratory plots

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I regularly used d_ply to produce exploratory plots.

A trivial example:

```
require(plyr)

plot_species <- function(species_data){
  p <- qplot(data=species_data,
        x=Sepal.Length,
        y=Sepal.Width)
  print(p)

}

d_ply(.data=iris,
      .variables="Species",
      function(x)plot_species(x))
```

Which produces three separate plots, one for each species.

I would like to reproduce this behaviour using functions in dplyr.

This seems to require the reassembly of the data.frame within the function called by summarise, which is often impractical.

```
require(dplyr)

iris_by_species <- group_by(iris,Species)

plot_species <- function(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width){

  species_data <- data.frame(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width)

  p <- qplot(data=species_data,
             x=Sepal.Length,
             y=Sepal.Width)
  print(p)

}


summarise(iris_by_species, plot_species(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width))
```

Can parts of the data.frame be passed to the function called by summarise directly, rather than passing columns?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you can work with `do` for this task with the same function you used in `d_ply`.  It will print directly to the plotting window, but also saves the plots as a `list` within the resulting `data.frame` if you use a named argument (see help page, this is essentially like using `dlply`).  I don't fully grasp all that `do` can do, but if I don't use a named argument I get an error message but the plots still print to the plotting window (in RStudio).

```
plot_species <- function(species_data){
  p <- qplot(data=species_data,
        x=Sepal.Length,
        y=Sepal.Width)
  print(p)

}

group_by(iris, Species) %>%
    do(plot = plot_species(.))
```